# how can we create an array-like object like `arguments`?

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

```
const arrayLike = {
    0: 0,
    1: 1,
}

arrayLike[Symbol.iterator] = () => {
    let index = -1;
    return {
        next() {
            index ++;
            return {done: arrayLike[index] === undefined, value: arrayLike[index]}
        }
    }
}

arrayLike.length = 2


console.log(Array.from(arrayLike))  // [1, 2]
console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(arrayLike)) // [1, 2]
```

we can add a length property or assign Symbol.iterator to create an array-like object.

Comment: `Array.from` would work regardless of your iterator. What are you trying to do here, exactly?

Comment: @ggorlen if you don't implement iterator or length, `Array.from` will return an empty array too.

Comment: @CodeAlien An iterator isn't necessary - see my snippet and [the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.slice). `.slice` worked before ES2015, and iterators were only introduced in ES2015

Comment: I didn't say don't implement length, I said don't implement iterator.

Answer (score 2):

You need to *call* `.slice` with a calling context of the arrayLike object. As is, with

```
Array.prototype.slice(arrayLike)
```

you're calling `.slice` with a calling context of `Array.prototype`, with an argument (the index to start slicing at) of `arrayLike`. `Array.prototype` is not actually array-like, so an empty array is returned.

Also note that the iterator isn't necessary.

```js
const arrayLike = {
    0: 0,
    1: 1,
    length: 2,
};

console.log(Array.from(arrayLike))
console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(arrayLike))
```

Assigning a `.length` to the object afterwards works fine:

```js
const arrayLike = {
  0: 0,
  1: 1,
};
arrayLike.length = 2;

console.log(Array.from(arrayLike))
console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(arrayLike))
```

Comment: thanks,
it works in browser, not in NODE. And I also found 
```
const arrayLike = {
 0: 0,
 1: 1,
}
arrayLike.length = 2
```
not work. WHY?

Comment: It works fine in node 12.14.1 for me. The code in the comment works fine for me too

Comment: I just installed Node 12.19.1 and it still works for me.

Comment: Do you know why  `const arrayLike = { 0: 0, 1: 1, } arrayLike.length = 2` is not work?

Comment: It does work, in both browsers and Node. Double-check your code.